# Giving a vertical bar height 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a container class. Inside that class are all my elements. Including the vertical bar (link-panel) and the div next to it (control_panel). I am trying to give my vertical bar height: 100%. I know I have to give the container class a height of 100% for it to work, but every time I try to do that the (control_panel) div runs on top of the footer (an element that is not in the container). I have made a jsfiddle of what I am experiencing, but please note that the footer in the real file is dynamically added to the HTML, so that is why I did not include it in my container class.)

I've also tried giving the body height 100%, but the body does not reflect any changes to the vertical bar because the vertical bar's parent is container. How do I make it so that I can achieve a vertical bar with 100% height that runs down to the footer? [Here's my jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pd5bLv63/)

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.control_panel {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.control_title {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.control_settings {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  height: 900px;
  width: 900px;
}
.link-panel {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
}
.link-panel ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.link-panel li {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class='control_panel'>
      <div class='control_title'>
        <h2>Your Settings</h2>
      </div>

      <div class='control_settings'>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="link-panel">
      <ul>


        <li>Dashboard</li>
        <hr>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <hr>
        <li><span><b>|</b> Settings</span>
        </li>
        <hr>
        <li>Contact Us</li>


      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--End of link panel div-->
  </div>

  <div class='footer'>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What if you assign a `background-color: #333333;` to `.container`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want child div to be of 100% height or their respective parent div, then you can use positions to achieve this.

See updated fiddle.

```
.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left:30%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
}
.link-panel {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pd5bLv63/3/

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.control_panel {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;  // A CHANGE HERE
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.control_title {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.control_settings {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  width: 900px;  // REMOVED HEIGHT HERE
}
.link-panel {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
}
.link-panel ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
.link-panel li {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Code order changed --->
<div class="container">
  <div class="link-panel">
    <ul>
      <li>Dashboard</li>
      <hr>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <hr>
      <li><span><b>|</b> Settings</span>
      </li>
      <hr>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--End of link panel div-->
  <div class='control_panel'>
    <div class='control_title'>
      <h2>Your Settings</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='control_settings'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='footer'></div>
```

Comment: This does not work when I start adding content to control_settings. The control_panel's height becomes greater than the link-panel's height. I want the height of the link-panel to be 100% of the page always.

Comment: Yes, the right panel should not move from its place

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
 html, body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.left-container {
    width: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.link-panel {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
}
.link-panel ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.link-panel li {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.right-container {
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    clear: right;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
.control_panel {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.control_title {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    height: 50px;
}
h2 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.control_settings {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 90%;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="left-container">
        <div class="link-panel">
        <ul>
        <li> Dashboard</li>
          <hr>
          <li> Blog</li>
          <hr>
          <li><span><b>|</b> Settings</span></li>
          <hr>
          <li> Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      <!--End of link panel div-->
      <div class="right-container">
      <div class='control_panel'>
        <div class='control_title'>
          <h2>Your Settings</h2>
        </div>
    </div> 

        <div class='control_settings'>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</div>
    </div>

    <div class='footer'>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```